# Gatsby.js - 404 page for nested project

Tags: github-pages, gatsby

I have a Gatsby.js project that I host through Github Pages.
The project is within a directory called `/an`
I'm deploying it through gh-pages package with the following command

`gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public -b master -e ./an`

I've followed https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/ to set the proper prefix path.
My custom 404 page is not detected through Github Pages. I believe it is because it has to be set on the repo root and not in /an.

How to tell GitHub Pages to use the 404 page generated in /an?