# ZEIT Now/GatsbyJS - Deploy to subdirectory

Tags: gatsby, vercel

I currently own a domain called *vidu.sh*
I want to deploy a Gatsby app through ZEIT now. I have already added and configured the domain in my dashboard (the domain was bought on an external service, I have changed the nameservers to match ZEIT's one and all's good)

The deployed application should be available on **https://vidu.sh/an**. (Please not that at the time I wrote this line, my app might be available as I had a previous configuration involving Github Pages. I want to migrate to ZEIT now because it match more my needs)

Is there a way to deploy the application to the asked URL without moving my gatsby app source into a directory called **"/an"/** ?

If there is no other choices than creating that **"/an"** directory, how should I configure the project to handle a custom 404 page? (See my [previous unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345552/gatsby-js-404-page-for-nested-project))

Basically, I want to use https://vidu.sh/an as the root of my application.

- https://vidu.sh should redirect to https://vidu.sh/an (HTTP 301)

So far, I have digged the following documentation, by I'm not able to link them to achieve what I aim for:

- [--prefix-paths](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/): A flag provided by Gatsby to note that an app will be hosted somewhere rather than on the root domain (/). I am not sure using the **now CLI** will automatically add this flag.
- [now.json](https://zeit.co/docs/configuration/#introduction/configuration-reference): I've understood that providing this file from my root directory will allow me to customize the behaviour of **now CLI** but I can't see what should be added to alter my build script.
- [Custom 404](https://zeit.co/docs/configuration/?query=404#routes/advanced/custom-404): It looks like it is somehow possible to match 404 to a nested folder through this, so "/an" solution seems to be the most viable. I just feel like that creating that directory is not the best option.

**UPDATE**:

I have tried the following `now.json` config:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/an",
      "destination": "/"
    },
    {
      "source": "/an/(.*)",
      "destination": "/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works but somehow I got redirected to the root domain.
I suspect it's a Gatsby behavior, things handled by ZEIT now directly do not alter the URL

- https://vidu.sh/an/blog
- https://vidu.sh/an/do-not-exist

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix my issue by using `rewrites` and `--prefix-paths`
Here is the solution:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "build": "gatsby build --prefix-paths",
   }
}
```

**now.json**:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/an",
      "destination": "/"
    },
    {
      "source": "/an/(.*)",
      "destination": "/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Calling now to deploy will use the build script with the flag. The server will be configured to use the rewrites rules!